# Database structure with different metrics/KPI categories

Tags: sql, database

What are the best practices to capture information for employees which have certain metrics which vary per unit in a database?

Example: Team 1 - daily basis
AHT = Measured by their total calls handled, total time spent talking to customers, total hold time, and total notation time
NPS = total surveys which are promoters, total which are detractors
Attendance = total login time versus total scheduled time

Do I create a table per metric? Like one table for AHT with EmployeeID and Date as the primary key? Should each value in the table (Talk Time, Hold Time, Notation Time) be in a separate row or separate columns (what if there is a new time considered in the future? I read that this is called repeating groups)?

Employee Table:

```
EmpID | Name
```

AHT Table:

```
  EmpID | Date | Talk | Hold | Notation | Calls
```

Or
   AHT Table:

```
  EmpID  | Date   | Metric 
     abc12 |  8/8/15 | Talk     
     abc12 |  8/8/15 | Hold
     abc12 |  8/8/15 | Notation
     abc12 |  8/8/15 | Calls
```

Survey Table:

```
  EmpID  | Date   | Metric 
     abc12 |  8/8/15 | Survey Count     
     abc12 |  8/8/15 | Promoter Count
     abc12 |  8/8/15 | Detractor Count
```

When I join these tables, I get duplicates though (using pd.merge in pandas, left join on EmpID+Date). For example, a new row would be made showing Talk time for each other metric in the Survey Table.

```
     EmpID  | Date   | Metric_x |  Metric_y 
     abc12 |  8/8/15 | Talk     | Survey Count    
     abc12 |  8/8/15 | Talk     | Promoter Count
     abc12 |  8/8/15 | Talk     | Detractor Count
```

At the end of the day I want a view which is still column based (useful for pivot tables for end users and Tableau).

```
EmpID | Date | Calls | Talk | Hold | Notation | Survey Count | Promoter Count | Detractor Count
```

Any advice? I want to try to make these raw data formats more efficient (coming from adding everything into one Excel sheet and vlooking.. tons of duplicated information, blank columns, formulas etc). Certain teams are measured by completely different metrics so it seems wasteful to have separate columns for each (others have the same name but different calculations too). There are a lot of metrics I did not add as well, so I imagine each should be a separate table with the EmpID and Date as a pk.

Comment: Use a separate column per measure, working with 'metric' (eav) type tables is horrible.

Comment: So is it better to have all measures as a column? My challenge is that there are over 20 different teams under me and all of them have different metrics and definitions, but some are standard across all. I need some of these metrics to roll up for all 20 programs and at least know if the other metrics are passing or failing.